# Creating containers with equal width in % for responsive website

Tags: html, css

I am wondering why my containers are not centered on the page.
I have my  with a width of 100%, my .body is 90% and the content of my body should be 70%. The content is centered within it's container. But for some reason my .body is not centered on the page. So I am trying to center my .body and thus the containing elements within it.

I tried inside my .body  and  #header{margin: 0 auto;}      (Didn't work)

HTML5 Code:`<body class="body">`
       `

```
    <section id="header" class="group">
     <header><h2><a href="http://www.epicforever.com">My Name</a></h2>
     </header>
     <nav class="main">
      <ul class="group">
       <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
       <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
       <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      </ul>
     </nav>

   </section>
   <section id="TopContainer" class="group"> 
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed diam nonummy nibh      
    liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil imperdiet doming id      
    quod mazim placerat facer possim assum. Typi non habent claritatem insitam.</p>   
   </section><section id="MidContainer" class="group"></section>
  </body>`
```

---

CSS3 CODE:
    html{
    width: 100%;
    }

```
body{
background-image: url("img/bg.png");
font-family: arial, 'Lucida Sans Unicode';
font-size: 87.5%;
line-height: 15px;
text-align: left;
color: #000305;
}

a{
text-decoration: none;
}

a:link, a:visited{
/*Fill in*/
}

a:hover, a:active{
/*Fill in*/
}

.body{
width: 90%;
margin: 1% auto;
height: 100%;
 }

 #header, #TopContainer, #MidContainer, #AboutContainer, #ContactContainer{
width: 70%;
 }

 #header{
height: 100px;
padding: 0 10% 10% 10%;
float: left;
line-height: 42px;
background-color: #fff;
 }

  #TopContainer{
height: 150px;
margin: 10% 0 0 0;  
padding: 0 10% 10% 10%;
float: left;
line-height: 42px;
background-color: #fff;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you were floating `#header, #TopContainer, #MidContainer` left, and setting them to 70% width. I removed the floats and added margin auto.

```
#header, #TopContainer, #MidContainer, #AboutContainer, #ContactContainer{
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

## [**click fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/3H9Qz/1/)

Comment: Yes indeed, it had to do with the floats: left & margin: 0 auto
Thank you Plato :)

Answer (score 0):

I typically don't like fiddling with the body in this manner, I would suggest creating an inner containing element and applying those styles to that instead.

```
<body>
    <page>
    ....
    </page>
</body>
```

But back to your problem, I think this would help:

```
html{text-align:center;}
```